# single app with different launches to configure and run in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a requirement to do an app to function like this.

Its an android application and it should have 2 launching methods.

- One is to proceed the function directly when touching the icon.
- Another icon should be there to give the setting to the same app to set the setting the settings of the android application.

Basically the app should work like the screen off and lock app in the market.

How can i achieve these 2 things in one app? When i install the app, i need to have two icons, one to do the functionality directly and other to set the settings of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to have to separate launchers (icons to start apps) in your app, launching two different activities.  This is easily achieved within your manifest.  Create two activities, say `MainActivity` and `SettingsActivity` and then declare them in manifest as launch-able - with different titles:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/main_activity_title"
  android:icon="@drawable/main_icon">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/main_app_title">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
  android:name=".SettingsActivity"
  android:label="@string/settings_activity_title"
  android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/settings_app_title">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When your app is installed, there will be two icons created: one to start the MainAcivity and another one to start SettingsActivity.